# Other papers like 'What is good mathematics ?'

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I recently read Terence Tao's **What is Good Mathematics** (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0702396.pdf)

It was a compelling read indeed. Can you recommend such short papers which are such insightful and not too complex (assuming advanced college student knowledge)?

Comment: This is a famous one of a similar nature: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9404236

Comment: Thanks for the link. That is indeed nice. There is one linked in the abstract of this paper, (has more to do with theoretical math and its connection to physics) which is also reasonably good: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9307227